# Pass Variable from Content page to Master Page in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, master-pages

I am new to classic ASP and I am trying to create a Master Page with variable placeholders and fill the information on that page with variables that are worked on a content page.

my master page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Template Loaded Properly</title>
</head>
<body>
  <% call BodyContent %>

  <span>Title: <% //place title here %></span>
  <span>Content: <% //place content here %></span>
</body>
</html>
```

and the content page like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="/templates/TEMPLATE.html" -->

<% sub BodyContent %>
var Title = "This is the title"
var Content = "Here goes some content"
<% end sub %>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you include the page with the variables, you can treat them as if they were created right then and there (because in a sense they *are* created right then and there, at least from the server's point of view). You *do* need to make the variables global in scope <sub><sup>[read: dim them *outside* the sub]</sup></sub>, unless you want to list all of them when calling your `BodyContent` sub. (Personally, I don't see the point, but some people are unreasonably allergic to global variables.)

```
<% 
dim Title, Content
sub BodyContent
    Title = "This is the title"
    Content = "Here goes some content"
end sub 
%>
```

```
<body>
   <% call BodyContent %>

   <span>Title: <%=Title%></span>
   <span>Content: <%=Content%></span>
</body>
```

One caveat, though: include files are processed long before the code, so you can't vary what file is included. In other words, **don't** do this:

```
<%If x = a Then%>
<!-- #include virtual="/templateA.inc" -->
<%Else%>
<!-- #include virtual="/templateB.inc" -->
<%End If%>
```

The result of trying something like that is that both templateA and templateB will be included. If you need conditional includes, look into using `FileSystemObject` to read the content of the appropriate template, and then using `Execute` to, well, execute it.

Comment: There's Server.Execute for dynamic includes, but it also got its downsides.